# StackExchange.redis - Redis Timeout On Batch

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to Insert 1M keys of hashes to redis using batch insertion.
When I do that, several thousands of keys are not being inserted, and I got **RedisTimeoutException**.

**Here is my code:**

```
IDatabase db = RedisDB.Instance;
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
var batch = db.CreateBatch();
  foreach (var itemKVP in items)
{
HashEntry[] hash = RedisConverter.ToHashEntries(itemKVP.Value);
tasks.Add(batch.HashSetAsync(itemKVP.Key, hash));
}
batch.Execute();
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

And then I get this exception:

RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response (outbound=463KiB, inbound=10KiB, 100219ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=HMSET, next: HMSET *****:*****:1390194, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 110, aw: True, rs: DequeueResult, ws: Writing, in: 0, in-pipe: 1045, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint: 10.7.3.36:6379, mgr: 9 of 10 available, clientName: DataCachingService:DEV25S, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=32763,Min=8,Max=32767), Local-CPU: 0%, v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

**I read the article and I didn’t succeed to solve the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

Well this might not be a foolproof answer, but you can certainly try this. When we use "batching" - even though the number of Redis calls could be reduced, it is understood that the batch is expected to take more time to process.

In our case increasing (Fine tune as per your infra) the `RedisConnectionTimeout` and `RedisSyncTimeout` values fixed the issue. FYR - we are using 7000 ms timeout.